# Mysql select date having mod result is equal to zero

Tags: mysql

My Table is

```
id name reg_date
1 ABC 2018-08-16
2 PQR 2018-08-10
3 LMN 2018-07-27
4 AAA 2018-01-01
5 BBB 2018-08-11
```

I want to get all user register on seven days interval before of given date. lets suppose I pass '2017-08-17'. Now I want to pass two date ('2017-08-17','2017-08-19'). so I want which date match betwwen this two date. right now mysql query is

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE
    MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE('2017-08-17')) -
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(reg_date)), 7*24*60*60) = 0
```

Result will be

```
id name date     match_date
2 PQR 2018-08-10 2017-08-17
3 LMN 2018-07-27 2017-08-17
5 BBB 2018-08-11 2017-08-18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find all dates falling on a 7 day boundary of one or more dates within a *range*.   First appreciate that if your date range is 7 days or greater, then *all* dates in the table will be returned by definition.  Not wanting to give you a solution heavily involving dynamic SQL, I instead chose to use an alternative.  For each row I compute whether that date would lie on a boundary with a date in your range.  If so, then that record is retained and the matching date from the range is displayed.  I encourage you to explore the demo below if you are curious about how this query works.

```
-- assign the bounds of the date range here
-- note that a range of 7 or more days will by definition simply return all records
SET @start_date = '2017-08-18';
SET @end_date   = '2017-08-17';

SELECT
    t.id,
    t.name,
    t.reg_date,
    CASE WHEN t.mod1 = 0 THEN @start_date
         WHEN t.mod2 = 0 AND @end_date <= @start_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
         THEN @start_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
         WHEN t.mod3 = 0 AND @end_date <= @start_date - INTERVAL 2 DAY
         THEN @start_date - INTERVAL 2 DAY
         WHEN t.mod4 = 0 AND @end_date <= @start_date - INTERVAL 3 DAY
         THEN @start_date - INTERVAL 3 DAY
         WHEN t.mod5 = 0 AND @end_date <= @start_date - INTERVAL 4 DAY
         THEN @start_date - INTERVAL 4 DAY
         WHEN t.mod6 = 0 AND @end_date <= @start_date - INTERVAL 5 DAY
         THEN @start_date - INTERVAL 5 DAY
         WHEN t.mod7 = 0 AND @end_date <= @start_date - INTERVAL 6 DAY
         THEN @start_date - INTERVAL 6 DAY
    END AS match_date
FROM
(
    SELECT
        id,
        name,
        reg_date,
        MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start_date) -
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(reg_date)), 7*24*60*60) AS mod1,
        MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) -
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(reg_date)), 7*24*60*60) AS mod2,
        MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start_date - INTERVAL 2 DAY) -
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(reg_date)), 7*24*60*60) AS mod3,
        MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start_date - INTERVAL 3 DAY) -
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(reg_date)), 7*24*60*60) AS mod4,
        MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start_date - INTERVAL 4 DAY) -
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(reg_date)), 7*24*60*60) AS mod5,
        MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start_date - INTERVAL 5 DAY) -
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(reg_date)), 7*24*60*60) AS mod6,
        MOD(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(@start_date - INTERVAL 6 DAY) -
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(reg_date)), 7*24*60*60) AS mod7
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE
    t.mod1 = 0 OR
    (t.mod2 = 0 AND @end_date <= @start_date - INTERVAL 1 DAY) OR
    (t.mod3 = 0 AND @end_date <= @start_date - INTERVAL 2 DAY) OR
    (t.mod4 = 0 AND @end_date <= @start_date - INTERVAL 3 DAY) OR
    (t.mod5 = 0 AND @end_date <= @start_date - INTERVAL 4 DAY) OR
    (t.mod6 = 0 AND @end_date <= @start_date - INTERVAL 5 DAY) OR
    (t.mod7 = 0 AND @end_date <= @start_date - INTERVAL 6 DAY)
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: now u got point. But date can be any i.e.2017-08-18. Beacuse 2017-08-18 date is between  '2017-08-17' AND '2017-08-25'.

Comment: @lbmgplus No, now I _don't_ get your point.  Edit your question and show data which makes it absolutely clear what you are asking.  Your current logic would return _all_ dates because the range covers an entire 7 day period.

Comment: can we use between operator here.

Comment: I want to find all dates falling on a 7 day boundary with  2017-08-17 between 2017-08-25

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question i think you can use BETWEEN keyword.

where columna_name between date1 AND date2